# kafka: Cancelled in-flight METADATA request, Disconnecting from node due to request timeout

Tags: events, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have spring-kafka:3.0.3, SSL  and I was  able to connect my consumer to the  bootstrap-servers and successfully consume  messages.

But apart of this I see log-messages like this

```
Cancelled in-flight METADATA request with correlation id 399 due to node 3 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 18275ms, elapsed time since send: 18275ms, request timeout: 60000ms)

Disconnecting from node 4 due to request timeout.
```

My research on stackoverflow and other sources mainly points me to threads, where the connection is generally failing due to wrong SSL/SASL config.

Since I can consume events this is not the case here.

Which timeout configuration I need to tweek?

Or is this a rather normal behaiviour?

Comment: b.t.w all is logged in INFO level, so it's normal ?